# PHP Mail with Recaptcha 2.0

Tags: php, html, email, recaptcha

I'm trying to get this email form to work using php but Im unfortunately not able to. What happens is that when I press submit, its just processing and chrome says "Waiting for localhost".

Some background: I am using WAMP locally and edited php.ini with gmail's smtp server with port 465.I am using the default mail function but I'm kind doubtful of it and think that since google needs authentication and so on I need to use libraries like sendmail. Having that said, I am just trying to send an email in core and dont care what library to use.

HTML Form:

```
<div id="email">
                            <div class="email-icon center">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <form id="contact" method="POST" action="sendmail.php">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control status-box" id="message" rows="4" placeholder="What's on your mind?" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdQ6wgTAAAAAHOj3FnhjZF6FMmUCC_r4FMdx2m2" data-theme="dark"></div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 center">
                                                <span class="input-group-button">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> SEND </button> 
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="response center"></div>
                        </div>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    require ("src/autoload.php");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $to = "example@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";

    $secret = "MY SECRET CODE";
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
    if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
        $captchaErr = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Please try it again.";
    } 
    else {
        $validCaptcha = true;
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
    else{
        $validEmail = true;
    }

    if ( $validCaptcha && $validEmail) {
        $sendMail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

    if ($sendMail) {
        $sendMailSucc = "";
    } 
    else {
        $sendMailErr = "";
    }
?>
```

PHP.INI Mail function

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = example@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = 

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
;mail.log = syslog
```

Also a note, I dont know why, but the PHP-smtp extension of WAMP has a danger sign and I think that can cause problems too.

I would appreciate any help. I would also appreciate it if someone could let me know how I can make this happen without opening a new page and send the email in-place.

Comment: don't use mail(). it's usually crap and near impossible to debug when things go wrong. use a proper mailer like phpmailer or swiftmail, both of which offer far better diagnostics when things blow up.

Comment: Ok I'll do that now. As far as the code goes, dont you find anything suspicious ?:)

Comment: nope. but that doesn't mean anything. my own home isp blocks outgoing smtp ports to anything but their own mail server as an anti-spam defence. your code could be 100% perfect and getting torpedoed by something upstream of your systme.

Comment: Huh. With the time that I'm spending to make this email thing work i could make two other websites...Is there any diagnostic tool to see the sockets or show what in the network is stopping it if its a network problem?

Comment: simple: fire up a shell, `telnet your.mail.sever 25` and see what happens. of port 465, if you're trying to use google's smtp as per your .ini...

Comment: So it turns out not only the default mail function sucks, but also gmail is really hard on authentication with its servers so I just used outlook's smtp.